# OData-like routes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing, odata

Is there a simple way for creating asp.net mvc application with routes based on OData uri conventions http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions ?

It's like a just adding new html format for specification.

Or may be another way for converting Urls into LINQ queries dynamically?

Comment: You can write object which build routes dynamically. But which your goal? For what tasks you need this?

Comment: Big forms for search with a lot of fields

Comment: There is simple linq to odata provider here: http://code.google.com/p/linq-for-odata/source/browse/?r=3#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fodata_linq%2Fodata_linq

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Domain Service Class which the wizard allows you to expose its methods as Odata out of the box. Just cause its MVC does not mean you can not attach on WCF etc.

Take a look at this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/16/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-odata-services.aspx

It explains how to use A Domain Service class to expose ODATA.

Comment: Thank you, but you give me link just on OData impl, I'm not shure that it can be works with html output (e.g. MVC Views).